# CPU and RAM needed to run Python code on Azure

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to recreate on of the charts found at the [RtCOVID-19](https://rt.live/) website, using a previously archived version of the code found [here](https://github.com/rtcovidlive/covid-model/tree/a87f1305c0f3fbdb4c25f5b05fffed26c3ef88c9). I am using Spyder via Anaconda to run the Python scripts.

After cloning the repo, I create a project and attempt to run the following lines of code, pulled from this [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/rtcovidlive/covid-model/blob/a87f1305c0f3fbdb4c25f5b05fffed26c3ef88c9/rtlive-model.ipynb) in the repo, which should output the tables needed to create the 'Oregon' graph.

```
import pymc3 as pm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import arviz as az
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from covid.models.generative import GenerativeModel
from covid.data import summarize_inference_data

from covid.data import get_and_process_covidtracking_data, summarize_inference_data

df = get_and_process_covidtracking_data(run_date=pd.Timestamp.today()-pd.Timedelta(days=1))

region = "OR"
model_data = df.loc[region]

gm = GenerativeModel(region, model_data)
gm.sample()
```

To see an example of the desired output, use the link to the Jupyter notebook referenced above.

The issue that I am running into is that my computer is not powerful enough to run the NUTS sampler. Whereas in the Jupyter notebook, we see that the authors are able to run the sample in 7m, my computer gives me an estimated run time of 4h and gets incredibly hot in the process. As such, I simply stop the model from running lest my computer explode into flames.

Some IT folks that I know said that they can create an instance in Azure to run these scripts, which would give me significantly more computing power, but they need to know how much CPU and RAM I need. Can anybody help me out with this? I only need to run the model one time, for example to recreate the Oregon chart, rather than all 50 charts as shown on the website. More generally, is the solution to this problem indeed to run the model in a cloud computing environment/is this possible?

Comment: I suspect that its easier to do tests and just figure out how much compute do you need, than us trying to guess it

Comment: Gotcha. Do you know how I would perform those tests or know of any resources that could show me how to do so?

Comment: well just create a vm and run your code, if CPU or memory are struggling stop the vm and resize it, takes like 1 minute. repeat if necessary